# How to alter characteristics of high frequency EM waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, scattering

I would know if it possible to alter characteristics of high frequency EM waves, ie altering the frequency, phase and/or amplitude.

I found it is possible to change frequency of ELF waves: http://rexresearch.com/puharelf/puharich.htm

If it is possible, what would be the simplest practical way to do it?

Comment: The article you linked is pseudoscience designed to elicit money from the gullible. The answer to your question is yes, but without a definition of what you mean by high frequency EM it is impossible to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is best done today using a frequency generator and modern ones will allow you to program quite complex waveforms. Isuggest your questionis best answered on the electronic stack exchange as your question seems more of a technical implementation or engineering.