# Shield against induction of sounds from remote source of RF waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, scattering

It has been demonstrated that it is possible to make humans hear sounds using waves.

Abstract From [Journal of Applied Physiology](http://jap.physiology.org/content/17/4/689)

> The intent of this paper is to bring a new phenomenon to the attention
>   of physiologists. Using extremely low average power densities of
>   electromagnetic energy, the perception of sounds was induced in normal
>   and deaf humans. The effect was induced several hundred feet from the
>   antenna the instant the transmitter was turned on, and is a function
>   of carrier frequency and modulation. Attempts were made to match the
>   sounds induced by electromagnetic energy and acoustic energy. The
>   closest match occurred when the acoustic amplifier was driven by the
>   rf transmitter's modulator. Peak power density is a critical factor
>   and, with acoustic noise of approximately 80 db, a peak power density
>   of approximately 275 mw/ cm2 is needed to induce the perception at
>   carrier frequencies of 425 mc and 1,310 mc. The average power density
>   can be at least as low as 400 μw/cm2. The evidence for the various
>   possible sites of the electromagnetic energy sensor are discussed and
>   locations peripheral to the cochlea are ruled out.

Is there a practical method for shielding? I mean using materials for simple attenuation, and/or altering characteristics of waves (frequency, phase and/or amplitude).

Comment: Related http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297408/how-to-alter-characteristics-of-high-frequency-em-waves

Comment: Note that your abstract is from 1962 --- surely there is other literature in the past fifty-four years which refers to this research. (My guess is that if there was anything to it, it would be a well-known trick today, so probably it was debunked.)

Answer (score 0):

A Faraday cage might not be the most practical solution, but would work as you require and would help confirm or deny whether humans sense EM radiation as described here.

*I've added a link since providing my answer for your convenience.
Its explained here better than I can:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage

Comment: I think this answer is fine: a Faraday cage is the most obvious way to shield against electromagnetic radiation, and there's a lot of literature on the subject.